# gcloud dataproc clusters create: No module named jsonschema

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

When trying to create a new cluster with `gcloud dataproc clusters create`, the following error is displayed:

> ERROR: gcloud failed to load (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create): Problem loading gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create: No module named jsonschema.
>
> This usually indicates corruption in your gcloud installation or problems with your Python interpreter.
>
> Please verify that the following is the path to a working Python 2.7 executable:
>      /usr/bin/python2
>   If it is not, please set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to point to a working Python 2.7 executable.
>
> If you are still experiencing problems, please run the following command to reinstall:
>       $ gcloud components reinstall
>
> If that command fails, please reinstall the Cloud SDK using the instructions here:
>      https://cloud.google.com/sdk/

Installing jsonschema does not seem to help.

Answer (score 7):

This was an issue with gcloud sdk release 208.0.0. Upgrading to 208.0.1 should resolve this issue.